# Is there a matrix satisfying a certain condition

Tags: matrices, orthonormal

I have a numerical problem which boils down to the following:

We are given a square matrix $R$, with a bunch of zeros in it. We want to check if there exists orthonormal matrix $T$ such that $TT'=I$, and $Q=RT$ has zeros in the same positions as $R$ does. (Of course $T$ cannot be the identity matrix.)

I am trying to check this in Matlab.

Thanks, Andras

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the previous result.

Here we can try to find out the property of $R$ step by step.[with updates]

We call the set $\{(i,j)\}$ as 'Z-set', if for matrix $R$, $R_{ij} = 0$.

- If $R$ is invertible upper or lower triangular matrix then
  $$Q = TR$$
  that means $QR^{-} = T RR^{-} = T$, since inverse of a upper triangular matrix is upper triangle matrix, thus $T$ is upper triangle, because the product of upper triangle matrices is upper triangle.
  But if a orthogonal matrix is upper triangle matrix, then it is $I$ or $-I$.
- If $R$ upper or lower triangular but not invertible.
  that means $QR^{+} = T RR^{+} $, $R^{+}$ is the Moore-Penrose inverse. If we write it out explicitly, then we can see that $T$ can written as direct sum of $I$(or $-I$) and another orthogonal matrix.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. The problem is not to find an R and T that satisfies the conditions, but to check if such a T exists for a given R! So R is given, not something to cook up. But thanks for the response @Yimin.

Comment: I see.@user2101255, I can say, if you take $T$ as a matrix with $0$ and $1$ as elements, then the effect is a permutation on the rows. So if your zeros in $R$ satisfy some symmetric pattern, then you will always find this $T$.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, @Yimin. I see how the special cases for upper or lower triangular R can be worked out. I don't think there is an easy general answer. But I do think I should be able to check the condition for a given R numerically, and that is all I need.